# docker-machine commands from C#

Tags: c#, docker, process, docker-machine

Is there another way to execute `docker-machine` commands from C#. Currently the way I'm doing it is:

1. Starting a `Process`
2. The `Process` starts `"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe"`
3. Pass the `docker-machine inspect default` command as a `ProcessStartInfo` argument

This is the code that I'm currently using and at the moment still don't have no idea how to retrieve the return JSON from the `docker-machine inspect default` command but I'm guessing that I it can be retrieved from the `process.StandardOutput` stream.

```
     ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo();
            psi.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
            psi.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\bash.exe";
            psi.WorkingDirectory = @"C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox";
            psi.Arguments = @"--login -i ""C:\Program Files\Docker Toolbox\start.sh""  docker-machine inspect default";
            psi.UseShellExecute = false;
            psi.RedirectStandardOutput = true;

 Process process = Process.Start(psi);
```

As you can see this is quite tedious to do, for instance if I have to do another couple of `docker-machine` commands.

I'm also looking at the [Docker Remote API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/) but I don't seem to see an endpoint that interacts with the Docker Machine.

**UPDATE:**

One problem that I have with executing commands this way is that sometimes the commands are not evaluated properly. For instance `eval $(docker-machine env default)` works if executed on the Docker Toolbox but not on the code.

Comment: Once you login you can create a text file that you can use for inputs for the rest of the commands.  the program would be to read a line from the text file and then send it to standard output.  What for response then read next line from text file and send next command.

Comment: @jdweng executing a series of commands isn't exactly my problem. it is just an example.another scenario: Check if the machine's memory is less than or equal to 1GB, if yes, stop the machine, upgrade the memory to 4gb and then start the machine. If the machine successfully started, deploy 2 containers to that machine and then check that the containers were successfully deployed. For this scenario, I may need to do some checks for a step before I proceed to the next step. For me I think it is easier to write the logic in C# so I'm looking for another way that I can execute commands individually.

Comment: Whyu not ask at docker forum.  Probably get better answer : https://docs.docker.com/opensource/get-help/.